# Given $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^+$ where $g(x) = 3^x$, define inverse function $g^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse-function

> Given $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^+$ where $g(x) = 3^x$, define fully the inverse function $g^{-1}$ and state the value of $g^{-1}(1)$.

This is what I have tried:

$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= 3^x \\
3^x &= y \\
x \log_3 3 &= \log_3 y \\
x &= \log_3 y \\
g^{-1}(1) &= \log_3 1
\end{align}$$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? This appears to be correct to me.

Comment: Who says it's wrong? Sure, $\log_3 1$ is a complicated way to write $0$, but not wrong.

Comment: Because my prof put question mark there. And he didnt explain. And I am not meeting him anymore. So thought of asking where i went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @StellaBiderman and Daniel

Comment: Thanks, @Winther I have updated my question. In my script it is $g^{-1}$

Comment: btw a simple way to check your answer and convince yourself that $g^{-1}(\color{red}{1}) = \color{blue}{0}$ is to check that $g(\color{blue}{0}) = \color{red}{1}$ which it has to be from the definition of the inverse.

Comment: Thanks, @Winther will surly keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's not untrue, but there are two reasons it might be marked wrong in a test.

1. You arguably didn't answer the first part of the question: The inverse of $g(x)$ is $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}(x) = \log_3 x$.
2. You didn't simplify your answer to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I agree to your pointers. this could be the reason my prof didn't give me marks and also didn't put it wrong. Which means I am partially correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be correct to me. The only thing that I think could have puzzled your professor is that $g^{-1}(1)=0$, but your answer isn't *wrong* as it too equals zero.